# Troubles on a determinat of a $4\times 4$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, gaussian-elimination

$$A = \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 3 & 1 & 0 \\
 1 & -1 & 2 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Its determinant is $7$ for I used Laplace method. I checked and it's $7$.

When I compute Guass reduction, though it is not $7$ anymore. I took into account the scale factor, but I do not know where I did wrong.

Those the operations I've made: the first two ones:

$$\text{Row 2} - \text{row 1} \to \text{row 2}$$
$$\text{row 3} - \text{row 1} \to \text{row 3}$$

No scale factor.

Then

$$\text{4 row 3} - \text{3 row 2} \to \text{row 3}$$
$$\text{3 row 4} - \text{row 3} \to \text{row 4}$$

At this point the matrix is

$$A = \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 3 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & -4 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & -3 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 7 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Dividing now the last row by $7$ and I get

$$A = \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 3 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & -4 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & -3 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Now the scale factor is $7$.

Yet this matrix is a scale matrix, hence the determinant is trivial that is $1\cdot (-4)\cdot (-3)\cdot 1 = 12$

And $12\cdot 7 \neq 7$. Where have I went wrong?

Comment: no mistakes, just there's a scale factor 12 (4 in your 3rd operation and 3 in your 4th )

Comment: @Exodd Oh! Thank you! I did not take them into account because our professor told that when you sum a row to a multiple of another row. I then think I understood it bad. Indeed I started by multiplying by $4$ and then by $3$ the rows...

Answer (score 1):

When you add or subtract a multiple of one row to/from another row, the coefficient of the latter row should be $1$. Thus properly:

$$\text{Row 2} - \text{row 1} \to \text{row 2}$$
$$\text{row 3} - \text{row 1} \to \text{row 3}$$

as given in the question, but then

$$\text{row 3} - \text{(3/4) row 2} \to \text{row 3}$$
$$\text{row 4} - \text{(1/3) row 3} \to \text{row 4}$$

where we divided by $3$ or $4$ to keep the target rows on the same scale.

Answer (score 0):

When yu add or subtract a multiple of one row to/from another row, the coefficient of the latter row should be $1$. Thus properly:

$$\text{Row 2} - \text{row 1} \to \text{row 2}$$
$$\text{row 3} - \text{row 1} \to \text{row 3}$$

as given in the question, but then

Answer (score 0):

While computing the determinant of a square matrix using the elementary row operations of the form $R_i=aR_i+bR_j$; just take care that either you choose $a=1$ strictly or if not, then divide the matrix by factor $1/a$. Since you have already used two such operations going with the later choice so you need to balance the determinant value of this matrix by $\frac{1}{4}.\frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{12}.$